# Is this transaction fee for contract creation normal?

Tags: tokens, erc-20, fees

I am creating erc20 token.
Transaction fee for it is about 0.3ETH.
Contract size is not big.
Is this price normal or am I doing something wrong?
Gwei 262.
Current Eth price 1917USD.

Contract :

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

import "./IERC20.sol";
import "./SafeMath.sol";


/**
 * @title NGEL token
 *
 * @dev Implementation of the basic standard token.
 * https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20.md
 * Originally based on code by FirstBlood: https://github.com/Firstbloodio/token/blob/master/smart_contract/FirstBloodToken.sol
 */
contract TestToken is IERC20 {
  using SafeMath for uint256;
  mapping (address => uint256) private _balances;
  mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) private _allowed;
  uint256 private _totalSupply;
  string public _name;                   // fancy name: eg xxx yyy
  uint8 public _decimals;                // How many decimals to show.
  string public _symbol;                 // An identifier: eg XXY
  address public owner;


 function TestToken (
     uint256 initialAmount,
     string tokenName,
     uint8 decimalUnits,
     string tokenSymbol
 ) public {
     _balances[msg.sender] = initialAmount;               // Give the creator all initial tokens
     _totalSupply = initialAmount;                        // Update total supply
     _name = tokenName;                                   // Set the name for display purposes
     _decimals = decimalUnits;                            // Amount of decimals for display purposes
     _symbol = tokenSymbol;                               // Set the symbol for display purposes
     owner = msg.sender;
 }


  /**
  * @dev Total number of tokens in existence
  */
  function totalSupply() public view returns (uint256) {
    return _totalSupply;
  }

  /**
  * @dev Gets the balance of the specified address.
  * @param owner The address to query the the balance of.
  * @return An uint256 representing the amount owned by the passed address.
  */
  function balanceOf(address owner) public view returns (uint256) {
    return _balances[owner];
  }

  /**
   * @dev Function to check the amount of tokens that an owner allowed to a spender.
   * @param owner address The address which owns the funds.
   * @param spender address The address which will spend the funds.
   * @return A uint256 specifying the amount of tokens still available for the spender.
   */
  function allowance(
    address owner,
    address spender
   )
    public
    view
    returns (uint256)
  {
    return _allowed[owner][spender];
  }

  /**
  * @dev Transfer token for a specified address
  * @param to The address to transfer to.
  * @param value The amount to be transferred.
  */
  function transfer(address to, uint256 value) public returns (bool) {
    require(value <= _balances[msg.sender]);
    require(to != address(0));

    _balances[msg.sender] = _balances[msg.sender].sub(value);
    _balances[to] = _balances[to].add(value);
    emit Transfer(msg.sender, to, value);
    return true;
  }

  /**
   * @dev Approve the passed address to spend the specified amount of tokens on behalf of msg.sender.
   * Beware that changing an allowance with this method brings the risk that someone may use both the old
   * and the new allowance by unfortunate transaction ordering. One possible solution to mitigate this
   * race condition is to first reduce the spender's allowance to 0 and set the desired value afterwards:
   * https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/20#issuecomment-263524729
   * @param spender The address which will spend the funds.
   * @param value The amount of tokens to be spent.
   */
  function approve(address spender, uint256 value) public returns (bool) {
    require(spender != address(0));
    _allowed[msg.sender][spender] = value;
    emit Approval(msg.sender, spender, value);
    return true;
  }

  /**
   * @dev Transfer tokens from one address to another
   * @param from address The address which you want to send tokens from
   * @param to address The address which you want to transfer to
   * @param value uint256 the amount of tokens to be transferred
   */
  function transferFrom(
    address from,
    address to,
    uint256 value
  )
    public
    returns (bool)
  {
    require(value <= _balances[from]);
    require(value <= _allowed[from][msg.sender]);
    require(to != address(0));

    _balances[from] = _balances[from].sub(value);
    _balances[to] = _balances[to].add(value);
    _allowed[from][msg.sender] = _allowed[from][msg.sender].sub(value);
    emit Transfer(from, to, value);
    return true;
  }

  modifier onlyOwner() {
    require(msg.sender == owner);
    _;
  }
  /**
   * @dev Internal function that mints an amount of the token and assigns it to
   * an account. This encapsulates the modification of balances such that the
   * proper events are emitted.
   * @param account The account that will receive the created tokens.
   * @param amount The amount that will be created.
   */
  function _mint(address account, uint256 amount) public onlyOwner {
    require(account != 0);
    _totalSupply = _totalSupply.add(amount);
    _balances[account] = _balances[account].add(amount);
    emit Transfer(address(0), account, amount);
  }

  /**
   * @dev Internal function that burns an amount of the token of a given
   * account.
   * @param account The account whose tokens will be burnt.
   * @param amount The amount that will be burnt.
   */
  function _burn(address account, uint256 amount) public onlyOwner{
    require(account != 0);
    require(amount <= _balances[account]);

    _totalSupply = _totalSupply.sub(amount);
    _balances[account] = _balances[account].sub(amount);
    emit Transfer(account, address(0), amount);
  }
}
```

Comment: I would say yes. use this calculator https://ethgasstation.info/calculatorTxV.php

Comment: welcome. better to wait until it is about 120 Gwei cause 0.3 is too much. and better to deploy it to a test net first and see how much it will cost for 120Gwei

Comment: Found this  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9xqoK2nKkM4 , could help you in the future for other contracts. You can use something like this " If you have a contract that will be deployed multiple times, it will deploy them cheaply." But please take care before using something like this, try to understand it because those tricks are too risky and need special code requirements.